# How to add extra amount to individual tax total?

Tags: magento2, tax-class, override-model, shipping-tax, tax-rule

> I have two tax rules in my online shop.
>
> 1. Tax 1
> 2. Tax 2
>
> The tax calculation is based on the subtotal. But now I want to add
> custom amount with the above tax .
>
> i.e., Tax 1 = Tax 1 + custom amount
> Tax 2 = Tax 2 + custom amount.
>
> [image]
>
> Where I need to change the logic in order to achieve this ?
>
> Any help is really appreciated.
>
> Thank you